# Android Studio import does not work

Tags: java, android-studio, import

I'm learning how to build android app & I have big problem. Namely, the import does not work.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jqIB.png)

I don't know why not work or whot I did not so. I tried:
-Uninstall & install Android Studio
-reboot
-Remove and add again system verible
unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javax classes are not included in the Android library.

You can use `android.media` instead.
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html)

Comment: thank you very much